# how to concatenate words of a string in python from a data file

Tags: python

I need to format these words

```
[’<html>’, ’<head>’, ’<title>’, ’This’, ’is’, ’the’,
’web’, ’page’, ’for’, ’exercise’, ’1’, ’</title>’,
’</head>’, ’<body>’, ’<h1>’, ’Hello’, ’world’, ’</h1>’,
’<p>’, ’Oh’, ’I’, ’do’, ’like’, ’to’, ’be’, ’beside’,
’the’, ’seaside’, ’</p>’, ’<p>’, ’Oh’, ’I’, ’do’,
’like’, ’to’, ’be’, ’beside’, ’the’, ’sea’, ’</p>’,
`’<p>’, ’Here’, ’is’, ’some’, ’<em>’, ’emphasised’,
’text’, ’</em>’, ’</p>’, ’</body>’, ’</html>’]
```

into something like this:

```
Page Title : The title of the ex1 page
HEADING: Hello world
PARAGRAPH: Oh I do like to be beside the seaside
PARAGRAPH: Oh I do like to be beside the sea
PARAGRAPH: Here is some *emphasised text*
```

I have so far used a loop for the tags, but do cannot think of an approach to format the words in between.

my code so far is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
url = "....." //removed 
data = urllib.urlopen(url)
tokens = data.read().split()

for token in tokens:
  if token == '<body>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '<title>':
    print "Page Title :"
  elif token == '<h1>':
    print "Heading:"
  elif token == '<p>':
    print "Paragraph:"
  elif token == '</p>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '<body>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '</body>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '</title>':
    print token == ''
  elif token ==  '</head>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '</h1>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '<em>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '<head>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '<html>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '</html>':
    print token == ''
  elif token == '</em>':
    print token == ''
  else:
    print token
```

What would I need to think of doing to complete this?

Comment: What about something which transforms an html string to a dictionary? I would try that first. Your solution seems to be the naive solution.

Comment: The first thing you show isn't a valid Python literal, the "curly quotes" won't work. I'd recommend you look into an actual HTML parser, like Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use 'BeautifulSoup'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html=requests.get('link')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
soup.find_all('title')
soup.find_all('a')
...
```

Comment: I don't think I could eligibly use this. Thanks